# Visual Studio - Can't reference tlb / dll anymore

Tags: visual-studio, tlb

I'm writing a C# application that communicates by a COM-Interface with another program. So far ervything worked well.

After I deleted the .tlb in the vs reference dialog and unregsitered it by reglibv12.exe I was not able to add it anymore.

The error says:

> Reference to *tlb path* could not be added. Please make sure the file
>   is accessible and that is it a valid assembly or COM component.

This problem occurs not at a collegues pc who uses also vs with default settings.

What I tried so far:
- Reinstalling Vs
- Delete the Vs user folder
- Register the tlb again with reglibv12.exe
- Run Vs as admin
- Put the tlb in the Vs project folder
- List the assemblys with Gacutil.exe \l -> Where my tlb was not listed

Answer (score 2):

Regtlibv12.exe is a dangerous tool.  It gets mentioned in web pages too often, programmers have discovered that it can provide a workaround for a license restriction.  Vendors tend to provide two distinct installers, one that installs the runtime support for a component and is free of charge, available to get the product installed on the user's machine.  And another one that you only get when you pay the license fee, meant to be used on a dev machine to write code that uses the component.  With the distinction that the former does not register a type library and the latter does.  Not wanting to pay the fee, or having only one license but used by multiple devs, or having a pointy-haired boss that thinks that one should be good enough for everybody and that software never changes, tends to make programmers look for alternatives.

Using it to *unregister* a type library never does anything useful in practice.  It merely destroys a registry key, it does not uninstall anything.  Destroying registry entries is a solution that usually only produces two new problems.  Also makes it very hard for the component vendor to help you, they just don't expect you to use a blunt tool like this.  Best thing to do is to use the vendor-provided installer and re-install the component.  You typically have to uninstall first to get everything back the way it should be.

There are three distinct ways to use a type library in a C# program:

- Project > Add Reference > COM tab > tick the entry in the list.  This is the best way and provides the best guarantee that your program can properly use the component and can keep up with changes in the component.  Only real hangup is that it isn't always terribly obvious what entry to pick if you only know the type library file name.  If necessary you can decompile the type library and find the description back, run OleView.exe > File > View Typelib.
- Project > Add Reference > Browse button > select the .tlb file or the executable file that has the type library embedded.  What you are trying to do right now.  Only necessary if the component is not registered on the machine or you intentionally want to build your program to target an older version of the component.  This is a brittle way, easy to get a mismatch between the type library you use and the actual installed component.  And unfortunately the error reporting is lousy, if the type library conversion is not flawless then it produces a "it did not work" error message.  The one you are looking at.
- From the Developer Command Prompt run Tlbimp.exe.  This generates the interop library up front, as opposed to the previous two bullets that do it at build time.  This is the best way to diagnose problems with the type library, the kind that make the 2nd bullet fail.  Or might be useful on a build server.  You'll see warnings if the type library contains entries that cannot be converted directly.  Which is pretty common and not necessarily fatal.  If you do it this way then you'd typically want the interop library in the project directory and checked-in to source control.  Use the Browse button to add the reference.  Do keep in mind that you will have to re-do this when the vendor component changes.

Focus on the first bullet.  I should note that having a .tlb file is fairly unusual.  In the vast majority of cases the component author will embed the type library in the DLL.  One reason might be that the component was actually developed in a .NET language, very easy to do with the [ComVisible] attribute.  The type library converter gets *very* sulky about that, insisting that you add a normal reference to the .NET assembly instead.